# Can we use Protobuf-net to serialize an ImmutableArray<T>?

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I'm trying to serialize a `System.Collections.ImmutableArray<byte>` member of a class using `protobuf-net v 2.0.0.668`.

According to the following article on Marc's blog, this is supported since r-666: http://blog.marcgravell.com/2013/09/fun-with-immutable-collections.html

However, I get an exception when deserializing the object:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object 
at System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableArray`1[T].get_Length () [0x00000] in <36486b016d234fca8cd67892bf29c7b5>:0
```

The (de)serialization works when I use a `System.Collections.ImmutableList<T>` instead of a `System.Collections.ImmutableArray<T>`

Is this expected? Is it recommended that I use `ImmutableList` instead?

Comment: this was a while ago, sorry but I missed this post somehow - do you have a minimal repro?

Comment: Sorry @MarcGravell, I clearly missed the notification on this post :P
I found that using the option `OverwriteList=true` resolved the issue